# orgmode beamer: set image width for source block output?

Tags: org-mode, beamer

This is one of my slides:

```
** Test image width

*** First sub                                          :B_block:BMCOL:
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_env: block
:BEAMER_col: 0.5
:END:
#+header: :exports results
#+BEGIN_SRC ditaa :file images/hello-world-round.png :cmdline -r
+--------------+
|              |
| Hello World! |
|              |
+--------------+
#+END_SRC

#+ATTR_LATEX: width=0.4\textwidth
#+RESULTS:
[[file:images/hello-world-round.png]]
*** Second sub                                          :B_block:BMCOL:
```

The `#+ATTR_LATEX: width=0.4\textwidth` does not work. I still get image with `width=\textwidth`.

How do I set width for the image exported by the `SRC` block?

Answer (score 6):

Dang! This line `#+ATTR_LATEX: width=0.4\textwidth` has got wrong syntax. It should be: `#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.4\textwidth`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why the documentation is messed up everywhere...