# Modifying the size of an asymptote image in latex export

Tags: org-mode, latex

I have been using Asymptote to make pictures that can be included in Latex documents. I recently discovered that Org mode plays well with Asymptote

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-asymptote.html#orgbded9e5

I was able to successfully compile a Latex document with embedded Asymptote code as follows.

```
#+TITLE: Test Document
#+AUTHOR: A. U. Thor
#+latex_class_options: [10pt]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}            
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{parskip} 
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{graphicx}                         
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{asymptote}
#+OPTIONS:      toc:nil 



#+BEGIN_SRC asymptote :file test.pdf
include graph;
size(1inch);
filldraw(circle((0,0),1),yellow,black);
fill(circle((-.3,.4),.1),black);
fill(circle((.3,.4),.1),black);
draw(arc((0,0),.5,-140,-40));
#+END_SRC
```

This generates the document as in the screenshot below. 
[image]

How can I adjust the instructions in the header of the code-chunk above, to be able to manipulate the size and placement (left/right/center) of the image? Right now the image is just too big.

***Note***: If it helps, the generated \LaTeX source file, exported from the Org file looks like this

```
% Created 2019-04-13 Sat 15:26
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\date{\today}
\title{Test Document}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={A. U. Thor},
 pdftitle={Test Document},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 26.1 (Org mode 9.1.9)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{test.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you include [this answer based on "#+ATTR_LATEX"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40991/orgmode-beamer-set-image-width-for-source-block-output/40992#40992) between your #+END_SRC and #+RESULTS block, you should be able to resize the image through LaTeX export.
Your code would look like this.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC asymptote :file test.pdf
<<Your Asymptote code here.>>
#+END_SRC

#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.2\textwidth
#+RESULTS:
<<The image Asymptote generated here.>>
```

Note that the "0.2" factor happened to work well with the document I was just working on; you might have to adjust it for your own use.

Comment: It is (always) a good idea to name your `SRC` blocks: that way, the `RESULTS` block is named as well and so when you evaluatte the `SRC` block again, no new `RESULTS` block is generated and you don't have to muck around with moving the `ATTR_LATEX` line and getting rid of the old `RESULTS` block.