# How to modify the width of an image in a column in a Beamer export in Org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, beamer

I would like to modify the width of an image in a column in Org-mode when exporting to Beamer but when I try to modify the `#+ATTR_LaTeX: width=1.5\textwidth` statement, it has not effect on the width of the images in the PDF produced, would anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

(I also tried the `#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.4\textwidth` syntax [mentioned here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/40992/2247) but I get an error during the export.)

Here is a MWE below:

```
#+TITLE: My ttitle
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [bigger]
#+options: H:2

* Section title

** Frame title

*** Column title 1 :BMCOL:
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_col: 0.5
:END:
#+ATTR_LaTeX: width=1.5\textwidth
[[./SomeImage1.png]]

*** Column title 2 :BMCOL:
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_col: 0.5
:END:

#+ATTR_LaTeX: width=1.5\textwidth
[[./SomeImage2.png]]
```

I'm on Org-mode 9.6 and GNU Emacs 27.2.

Comment: I don't know what error you get but `#+ATTR_LaTeX: :width 0.6\textwidth` does not produce an error for me, and moreover it works in that it changes the width of the image depending on the mulitplier. If you cannot get it work, please add the error message you get to the question.

Comment: You're right it works! It seems I had another `#+ATTR_LaTeX:` that caused an error in the export to LaTeX. Thanks! :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no problem: the OP made a mistake and what he reported as a problem is not really a problem.